# How to transfer Raphaeljs variable in a JSP page?

Tags: raphael

I'm in a position to get a value from JavaScript, which uses Raphaeljs and send it to a Servlet/JSP page for Display & DB related work. Kindly assist me for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do AJAX for this one. Be sure to load jQuery so is easy to do it.

Simply collect the var value and send it to the JSP using .get or .post. Then you can add your validation in the JSP for the value sent and do whatever you want with it.

Hope this helps!

Jorge C.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand this is not Raphael related. 
What you need to make sure is, that you understand the difference between client and server side. Javascript runs client side (given we're not talking about a server side application written with JS/nodejs) in the browser while JSPs are executed on the server

If you collect values via JS and want the server to process it then you you can either send it to the server with an AJAX request (which wont reload the page) or manipulate a form and submit it (which will be a GET or a POST request then and will reload the whole page).

On the server you can accept the values and process them and then render the response.

For Ajax request you could look at jQuery.